# How to make Label Text Underline?

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, underline

How can I make `Label` text `Underline` in WPF? I am stucked and could not find any property for underline:

```
<Label Name="lblUserName"
       Content="Username"
       FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium" />
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In `Label` no [`TextDecorations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.TextDecorations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), therefore try this:

```
<Label Width="100" Height="30">
    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">TestText</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

**`Edit: more universal solution`**

In this case, instead of `Label.Content` using `Label.Tag`, because Content property can be set only once:

```
<Label Tag="TestContent" 
       Width="100" 
       Height="30"
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
       Background="AliceBlue">

    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" 
               Text="{Binding Path=Tag, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                             AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}" />
</Label>
```

Comment: FYI, if you need to do this in the code behind (with a dynamically created component) the code is: YourTextBlockName.TextDecorations = System.Windows.TextDecorations.Underline;

Comment: If you want to make use of access keys (i.e. focusing the label's target by pressing `ALT` + [AccesKey]) you should use `AccessText` instead of `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to apply the style directly to the Label:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This simplifies the label items:

```
<Label>
    Label 1
</Label>

<Label Grid.Row="1">
    Label 2
</Label>
```

This works if the content of the labels text only.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer with styles.

Content:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource StyleName}">text content</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

And the style:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleName">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
</Style>
```