# Underline a Label

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, label, .net-3.5

I am trying to underline a label as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609341/how-to-make-label-text-underline) but it does not work. An error appears saying:

```
Mode must be specified for RelativeSource
```

But I have already indicated it:

```
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Tag="ID" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
         <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}"    />
   </Label>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: That works for me. Try to rebuild all. And why don't you directly use a TextBlock? There seems to be no need for the Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be alright. I used your code in my VS, that message only appeared once, once I clean and rebuilt the code, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying glitch of visual studio. Just rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how this should actually be done by setting the Label's `Template` property instead of the `Tag` property workaround:

```
<Label Content="ID" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Label.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
            <TextBlock Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       TextDecorations="Underline"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Content,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Label}}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Label.Template>
</Label>
```